# Why can't I connect to remote mysql server with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql server which can be accessed by going abcdef.com/phpmyadmin. but why can't I access with pdo in php, error Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] occurs

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=abcdef.com;dbname=db", "root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

Is there a problem with web server and mysql server which are in different computer?

Comment: Have you tried login in CLI? What's the error?

Comment: no, logging in with CLI is different from phpmymin? sorry, i don't really know it . Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  with the php page

Comment: Typically a mysql server is _not_ accessible via the internet, since that is a security thread. So you will have to take special actions for it to be reachable. You have to configure it such that it listens to a port and you have to make sure that no firewall blocks incoming connections.

Comment: i can access the server through phpmyadminn, doesn't it mean that is not blocked?

Comment: try replacing `abcdef.com` with `localhost`

Comment: @pinkalvansia the mysql server is in a remote computer, btw it works to localhost for testing

Comment: @arkascha is right, the MySQL port is likely blocked by a firewall. When you access the server via web, it's usually by using port 80 or 443 (HTTP / HTTPS), whereas a direct connection to a MySQL server usually uses port 3306.

Comment: In cpanel, in remote databases, add the ip address from which you are trying to access the database.